# Faire du/des progrès

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Est-ce qu'on dit:

> *Je fais **du** progrès OU je fais **des** progrès.*

> *Il fait du **progrès** avec sa thèse* OU *il fait **des** progrès avec sa thèse*

Selon un ami français il faut utiliser *des* dans la première phrase mais *du* dans la deuxième... Est-ce vrai?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non, dans les deux phrases « des » est le seul article utilié : [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+fais+du+progr%C3%A8s%2Cje+fais+des+progr%C3%A8s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20fais%20des%20progr%C3%A8s%3B%2Cc0).

Remarquez que la différence entre   « Je fais des progrès » et « il fait du progrès » n'est qu'un changement de personne du verbe ; ces changements ne peuvent pas avoir d'incidence sur les articles  indéfinis (des) et partitifs (du) ; si on emploie un article donné pour une personne donnée on l'emploie aussi pour les autres personnes, sinon il y aurait une incohérence dans le langage.

On utiliserait « du » ou « des » dans la formulation suivante. ([linguee 1](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/il+y+a+du+progr%C3%A8s+%C3%A0+faire.html), [linguee 2](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/il+y+a+des+progr%C3%A8s.html))

- Il y a du/des progrès dans le travail sur sa thèse.

Il était encore possible de dire « faire du progrès » au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise/Qb4SAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fait+du+progr%C3%A8s%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)) et on trouve encore quelques occurrences de « faire du progrès » ; un examen de [cette page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fait%20du%20progr%C3%A8s%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) (faire attention aux faux positifs) montre cependant que quasiment  tous les cas se trouvent avant le XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Comment: Au Canada, on trouve faire du progrès. A partir de là, on ne peut que faire du progrès, n'est-ce pas ? https://vigile.quebec/auteurs/archives-de-vigile?comments_page=171&page=19